# UFT: SetCellData issue PbDataWindow for radio button

Tags: radio-button, powerbuilder, hp-uft

I have a radio button that is represented as a pbdatawindow, when I run setcelldata to pick an option it works fine on my laptop but fails on my colleagues laptop. If we try the run the command again on my colleagues laptop we get a fatal error from UFT.

The only difference between my UFT install and my colleagues is that my colleagues version is installed in French. Has anyone seen a similar issue?

PbWindow().PbDataWindow().SetCellData 1,1,""

Answer (score 0):

Few things to try:

What version of uft are you using? - perhaps check for newer of see if there is a patch available?
Jump onto the microfocus knowledge base and see if there is anything around power builder.

You say the machines are the same but does that include every application too?  In the past I've known that if you install applications after uft it can break its references. Try uninstalling and reinstalling uft. There is a repair option but uninstall/reinstall is normally more thorough.

Try and clear out all your temp and user settings.

- In your user profile backup then remove all folders with mercury, hp, Hewlett-Packard and microfocus.
  -The go to %temp% and clear evetything.

Try and pin down the problem - Has your colleague tried the English version or uft?  - if that works, is it an option? (everyone use the same version)

If it doesn't work it suggests it's your colleague's machine as opposed to uft.
Is evetything such as the resolution and browser/application versions the same? Or simply try another French localised machine?

What's the fatal error? Does it provide any clues on why it failed?

Finally, You're paying a lot for commercial software. Don't suffer in silence :-)
Log a support call with microfocus. It's a bit long winded but Back in the day they used to be pretty good at helping. They'll ask you for logs and knowing how to get that is good to know.

There's more to try - let me know how you get on.